# How do memory addresses know how long an an array is?

Tags: c, memory, c-strings

I guess I can tag C++, Assembly and C as memory management works similarly in all languages.

I've just hit the stage in C where I'm learning pointers. I understand that if you store a string (or in C, better known as a char array) it's actually just an address in memory of the first element of that array.

How does this first element of the array know how much it has to count for the whole array, my own guess is it stops at the first occurrence of `\0` but am I right? I've ben told `\0` is a sign that the array has finished that you've hit the last element (or technically, 1 after the last element).

I guess I posted this for validation of my maybe-right-answer. Can anyone explain it in better detail?

Comment: The short answer: it doesn't. It's up to you, the lowly programmer, to know how long your arrays are, and write your code appropriately. If you don't, your program will explode in a thunderous fireball, crashing and burning until only dust is left.

Comment: The first element doesn't know anything about it neighbors. If you are dealing with a *nul-termianted* string, then the code simply scans forward over each character until `'\0'` is encountered. (which must be within your array/memory bounds) If it is an array of chars (not a string), then YOU are responsible for knowing how many characters fit within YOUR array bounds. (no tricks...)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.

Use a too-large value as an index and you read from/write to memory outside of the array.

Do it in C++ and the optimizer may cache data and not refresh it and get insane program states (UB).

Now, copy an array in a struct via `=`?  Size is then known at compile time, similarly no runtime markers used.

Comment: It's really hard adapating to the fact you NEED to know the index count of your arrays for pretty much any kind of string, coming from an language like C#, but thanks. This cleared it up.

Comment: There are tools (some of them are builtin to the compiler these days) that can check array bounds for you, but the C or C++ language standards do not specify a check is required, only that it is undefined to go (too far) beyond the bounds.

Comment: @chaotic If instead of raw arrays you use std vector, length is stored at compile time.  If you use std array, you get checked indexing with at.  You can get types that can check, but also tyoes that do not.

Answer (score 0):

In those low-level languages, you can access an array even past what is allocated. You have to manually keep track of how long the array is. However, there are different data types, like linked lists, that can be built to keep track of the beginning and end of the data. For example, in Python, there are "lists" instead of "arrays", and the size of the list can be found out using the "len" built-in function.

Comment: Legally, you can only access 1-past the end (though you cannot dereference that address), anything beyond invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, memory addresses do not "know" how long an array is. It all depends on your computer architecture and is discovered through CPU instructions. When you access the first element of the array, an instruction is decoded by your CPU and will proceed to grab the first byte of data in the given memory address. This first byte of data should contain an ascii value that pertains to a specific char element and will display your desired character. If you iterate through the string and implemented it correctly, there typically is a null character to which you can end your iteration. However, do note that the null character is not guaranteed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that if you store a string (or in C, better known as a
>   char array) it's actually just an address in memory of the first
>   element of that array.

A [narrow] string literal has type `char[C]` where `C == 1+strlen(s)` (the 1 is for the `'\0'` at the end, which the `strlen` function excludes from its return value).

If you store a string literal in a variable of type `char*`, then it's indeed as you say: just an address in memory of the first element of that array.  That is how "array decay" works.

If, however, you store a string literal in a variable of type `char[N]`, then how things work depends on `N` and `1+strlen(S)` (where `S` would be a string literal).  If `N < 1+strlen(S)`, then only the first `N` chars are stored in the `char` array, and the array is not terminated by `'\0'`.  If `N >= 1+strlen(S)`, then all chars of `S` are stored in the `char` array, and any elements in excess of `1+strlen(S)` are zero-initialized per usual for arrays.

> How does this first element of the array know how much it has to count
>   for the whole array, my own guess is it stops at the first occurrence
>   of `\0` but am I right? I've ben told `\0` is a sign that the array
>   has finished that you've hit the last element (or technically, 1 after
>   the last element).

The first element doesn't store the count of the array unless you make it that way.  In the case of storing a string literal or any other `char` array in an object of type `char*`, you're discarding the size info, unless you stored the size in the first element manually (strings in the Pascal programming language do this).  Whether or not you stored the size, you're still responsible for tracking the size info.  If you initialize an object of type `char[N]` with a string literal, you keep the size info of the array, and the compiler tracks all `N` chars for the lifetime of the array.